# Xcode 6 contraints issue

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, size

i am struggling with the new iOS constraints that Apple have included into the Xcode. i have seen youtube videos and followed them exactly right but i still seem to be having issues. basically i am trying to draw two separate size and coloured views onto the view controller and trying to align them so they appear on exactly the same place without being stretched on each iPhone screen e.g. 3.5, 5.5 etc. I have tried pinning the top one to top layout guide as required and bottom one to bottom layout guide and i have also done the leading and trailing space of both views as well as identifying the vertical spaces between both the views and all the lines do turn blue but for some reason it doesn't align how its meant to and it also ends up resizing one of the views. its really starting to annoy me! please any help is much appreciated. i followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng

thanks

Comment: Pics? Or it didn't happen.

Comment: well i have given you the link to the video which i am following so i am not claiming its my work so why would i be lying?